# What kind of programming pattern is appropriate for programming an algorithm with rules and exceptions?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm interested in coming up with an algorithm to solve a guessing game. The player is attempting to guess a sequence of 4 unique numbers from 1 to 9. After a guess, they are told how many numbers of their guess are correct and in the correct position and how many are correct and in the wrong position.

The approach I'm taking is to have a starting collection of all of the possible guesses and a collection of all the possible numbers. The collection of guesses is used to give the player an idea of all valid guesses remaining. The collection of numbers stores information about each digit:

- whether it is definitely present or definitely not, and
- which position it is definitely in or definitely not in.

Then, as the player is given more clues, I remove all guesses that must be invalid and update assumptions about the digits. The idea is that, after a certain number of guesses, the algorithm should continue to improve their odds of choosing the correct sequence.

I want to accomplish the process of striking items off of the list and making assumptions about the digits by creating rules. Whenever a rule's conditions are met, the number collection and/or guess collection should update. Rules should include:

- if the current guess has no numbers in the correct position, all numbers in the sequence are definitely not in their current position,
- if 4 of the numbers in the sequence are present, then all guesses without all 4 of these numbers are invalid,
- if two guesses have 8 unique numbers between them and the sum of present numbers is only 3, then the 9th digit not guessed is definitely present,
- etc.

I like the idea that I, as the developer, can continue to add rules as I discover patterns that I have not noticed (or have not been able to formalize) without much hassle. The problem lies in implementation.

**Is there a programming pattern that allows me to make an extendable set of rules to test for and react to?**

Comment: [Peter Norvig's article on constraint propagation](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html) is a recommended reading. The article uses Sudoku as an example but it is applicable to many types of number filling games as well.

Comment: Not a pattern, but there are declarative logic programming languages that would solve these problems nicely.

Comment: FYI, this problem is known as [*"Bulls and Cows"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_cows), which might help you find relevant resources.

Comment: I wrote a version of that game, but in my version the human plays and the program gives feedback. My program doesn't guess.

Comment: For this kind of game design you must use OOP(Object Oriented Programming) concept, Specifically JAVA/Python with arrays. Arrays and variables will be used to store and guess. create objects within which you can accumulate the guesses and call it using several methods regarding the answer of a question you want. Hope the discussion will help you to find the right path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might also look into [expert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system), [business rule engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine), [declarative programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming), [inference engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inference_engine), [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), [Rete algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm), [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog), [Datalog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datalog), [CLIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLIPS), [metaknowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaknowledge), [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming), [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29), etc...

[J.Pitrat's blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/) has interesting entries, e.g. [Know thyself](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2014/03/know-thyself/) etc...

> Is there a programming pattern that allows me to make an extendable set of rules to test for and react to?

Yes, it is called an *expert system* (and is probably more a programming paradigm, or even a buzzword, than a programming pattern), the set of rules and facts being called the [knowledge base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_base)

Experts systems have been in vogue in the 1980s & 1990s. Then came the so called [AI winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI_winter) (where AI meant [artificial intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) - an expression whose meaning has varied a lot during time).

<sup>*Off-topic:* I believe that the next AI winter would be an [*Abstract Interpretation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation) winter. [Static analysis of source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) is today also a buzzword, even if [formal methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods) are very useful, but they are not the [silver bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet) that some people proclaim.</sup>

[AGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence) (artificial general intelligence) is however a very interesting research field.

Comment: I just read an article on Prolog yesterday that said it would be good for that sort of task.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is comparable to a program simulating a chess player. When in need of using a set of knowledge rules to produce the most suitable decisions, the logic programming seems to be the ideal solution. Using such a programming language (like Prolog), you can define the whole set of rules that govern your 'world', and finally you have to create a query regarding the ways in which a specific logical statement can become true. The program will execute all the possible paths from the initial condition to the final one, and it will output all the possible solutions. However, be aware that if the decision tree has too many branches, then this will be quite cpu-stressful.

On the other side, you can use a procedural language (like Java or perhaps R would be good, since it is focused on Machine Learning features). You can implement on your own one of the well-known Pathfinding algorithms (established by the AI community) to dynamically solve your problem. Each node in your graph will correspond to a decision state and the target node will be the final state. In the web you can find a lot of tutorials and demos of implementations of those algorithms.